# Pure Ruby (not C) Markdown library

Tags: ruby, markdown

I'm looking for a Markdown library, written purely in Ruby (not C, or anything else). I need to use it as an example because I am having to write my own. Do you know of a pure Ruby implementation of a Markdown processor?

Comment: If you're writing your own, I'd advise looking at at an example in a different, but similar, language (Perl or Python would be good candidates). You'll get a better understanding of what you're doing, because you'll have to think about how to adapt it to Ruby's paradigms. If you're using an example in the same language, you're more likely to re-implement things without really understanding them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Searching the gems repository for Markdown](http://rubygems.org/search?query=markdown) yields a variety of hits:

- **[kramdown](http://kramdown.rubyforge.org/)** —  *Yet-another-markdown-parser but fast, pure Ruby, using a strict syntax definition and supporting several common extensions. It is probably the fastest pure-Ruby Markdown converter available (January 2011), being about 4x faster than Maruku and about 5x faster than BlueFeather.*
- **[Maruku](https://github.com/nex3/maruku)** — *A pure-Ruby Markdown-superset interpreter.*
- **[BlueFeather](http://ruby.morphball.net/bluefeather/index_en.html)** - *Software for converting text written by extended Markdown like PHP Markdown Extra to html. It is pair of command-line tool and pure Ruby library.*

I'm personally using kramdown for my blog on [phrogz.net](http://phrogz.net), and it's been working like a charm. I particularly like some of its extensions, such as the ability to apply custom attributes (e.g. CSS classes) to elements and custom `id` attributes to headers.

Comment: kramdown has been my go-to Markdown parser for a while. Very nice, and supports the github extensions.

Comment: Maruku looks like a dead project. The last update was done nearly two years ago, and the most other parts were last updated nearly three years ago. And on top of that, the name is wrong. The author claims that the name "Maruku" is the romanization of the Japanese word borrowed from the English word "mark". But that is entirely wrong. The romanized Japanese word is "maaku".

Comment: what about the infamous code-blocks-under-list-items issue? i have not yet to see any parser other than maruku to resolve this, but maruku poses problems of its own so i'm reluctant to using it. can kramdown handle those issues?

Comment: @EliranMalka Yes: you can either used [fenced code blocks](http://kramdown.rubyforge.org/syntax.html#fenced-code-blocks) or the [EOB Marker](http://kramdown.rubyforge.org/syntax.html#eob-marker) to place a code block after a list item (and not as a child of the list item) without any `&nbsp;` hackery needed.

Comment: thanks a lot, i'll try these tomorrow. i should probably post a new question on the subject. will invite you over to post an answer should it happen.